# How to use Newtons Method with a given interval

Tags: python, sympy, newtons-method

I can calculate the root of a function using Newtons Method by subtracting the old x-value from the new one and checking for the convergence criterion. Is there a way of doing it when given a closed interval, e.g

Given a function and the interval [a,b] = [0.1, 3.0], the convergence criterion will be calculated by checking if [3.0 - 0.1] < 0.000001, i.e [b-a] < 0.000001.

The code I provided is calculating the convergence criterion using the x-values. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can use the interval instead of the x-values.

```
from math import *

x = 1.0 #initial value

for j in range(1, 101):
    xnew = (x**2 + cos(x)**2 -4*x)/(2*(x - cos(x)*sin(x) -2))

    if abs(xnew - x) < 0.000001:
        break
    x = xnew

print('Root = %0.6f ' % xnew)
print('Number of iterations = %d' % j)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are wanting to guarantee that the root is found within a given interval (which is not something the Newton-Raphson can guarantee). You could use bisection for this. If you know the function changes sign in a given interval (and is continuous in the same) then something like the following works:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> from sympy import nsolve
>>> ivl = 0,3
>>> expr = (x**2 + cos(x)**2 -4*x)
>>> nsolve(expr, x, ivl)
0.250324492526265
```

But it also looks like you might have some variables mixed up in what you are trying with the NR method. The `xnew` you are calculating looks very much like `f(x)/f'(x)` which is `dx` in `xnew = x - dx`. So if you write:

```
for j in range(1, 101):
  dx = (x**2 + cos(x)**2 -4*x)/(2*(x - cos(x)*sin(x) -2))
  if abs(dx) < 0.000001:
    break
  x = x - dx

print('Root = %0.6f ' % x)
print('Number of iterations = %d' % j)
```

you will get

```
Root = 0.250324 
Number of iterations = 4
```